# ReactJS: Validation okay, but didn't return anything

Tags: reactjs, validation

I made a email verification input using React JS that automatically gives an error if I didn't write the valid email address.

This is my validate function:

```
export const validate = e => {
  let error = [true, ''];
  if (e.validation.email){
    const valid = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(e.value);
    const message = `${!valid ? 'Must be a valid Email' : ''}`;
    error = !valid ? [valid,message]: error;
  }
  if (e.validation.required) {
    const valid   = e.value.trim() !== '';
    const message = `${!valid ? 'This field is Required' : ''}`;
    error = !valid ? [valid,message]: error
  }
  return error
};
```

All this validation are referred to this state from another file:

```
state = {
    formError  : false,
    formSuccess: '',
    formdata   : {
      email: {
        element          : 'input',
        value            : '',
        config           : {
          name       : 'email_input',
          type       : 'email',
          placeholder: 'Enter your Email'
        },
        validation       : {
          required: true,
          email   : true
        },
        valid            : false,
        validationMessage: ''
      }
    }
  };
```

All validation error message will be put on `showError()` function and I already input it on `formFields.js`. And this is the `formFields.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';

const FormField = ({formdata, id, change}) => {

  const showError = () => {
    let errorMessage = <div className="error_label">
      {
        formdata.validation && !formdata.valid ?
          formdata.validationMessage
          : null
      }
    </div>
    console.log(errorMessage);
    return errorMessage;
  };

  const renderTemplate = () => {
    let formTemplate = null;
    switch (formdata.element) {
      case('input'):
        formTemplate = (
          <div>
            <input
              {...formdata.config}
              value={formdata.value}
              onChange={event => change({event, id})}
            />
            {showError()}
          </div>
        );
        break;
      default:
        formTemplate = null;
    }
    return formTemplate;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {renderTemplate()}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormField;
```

I already drilled down and do `console.log()` on every variable and data I wrote and from React Tab.

When I Input the wrong e-mail:

[image]

When I empty the field:

[image]

When I type a valid email:

[image]

The validation error message was updated on that state but when I `console.log(errorMessage)` on `showError()` function, it returns like this which is the possible main problem:

[image]

What I expected from `console.log`-ing `errorMessage` is a `div` tag with error message. but I just got bunch of object data.

What code did I input wrong? Did I miss something in the code?

Comment: looking your object in your console your are getting `<div className="error_label"></div>`. As you are `console.log`-ing `console.log(errorMessage);`. `errorMessage` in your code is a React element and React elements are object. See the object in console has `type: div ` and `props: { className: "error_label", children: "" }` properties  which is evaluated by React as  `<div className="error_label"></div>`

Comment: so the `div` is supposedly working? But why it didn't appear on my website?

Comment: I try to `console.log`-ing `formdata.validationMessage` and I only get a empty value only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshots, you put the error message in `formdata.email.message` but the `formdata.email.validationMessage` is always empty, and in your `showError` you only use `validationMessage` that is why you see empty message.

```
const showError = () => {
    let errorMessage = <div className="error_label">
      {
        formdata.validation && !formdata.valid ?
          formdata.validationMessage /*This is always empty*/
          : null
      }
    </div>
    console.log(errorMessage);
    return errorMessage;
  };
```

Comment: It looks like I throw the message to the wrong object state that I didn't include the code how I write those. But I already fixed it and now the code works well

Comment: Glad it helped.